How much payload could the Falcon 9 send to geostationary orbit?
How much could a fully expendable Falcon 9 lift to GEO? How does this number change if the Falcon 9 performs a drone ship landing or an RTLS landing?
To further add to the confusion, Encyclopedia Britannica’s article on Falcon 9 claims that it can send 8,300 kg (18,300 pounds) to geostationary orbit, which SpaceX lists as Falcon 9’s capacity to GTO.

Usually a LEO rocket can not launch anything into GEO, because their engines can not restart. The 8300kg is probably the GTO capacity, not GEO.

@user3528438 the falcon 9 second stage can restart

@user3528438: Why would a LEO rocket not be able to restart its engines? Starlink gets deployed to about as low a LEO orbit as it gets (284 km × 294 km) and needs a circularization burn by the upper stage at apogee, and that works just fine. The Transporter and Bandwagon missions typically need multiple upper stage engine relights. Oh, and of course, they must be able to relight for their deorbit burn anyway.

First, the Encyclopedia Britannica is wrong.
According to SpaceX themselves, F9 puts 8300kg into GTO, not GEO.
The difference is that GTO (Geostationary Transfer Orbit) is the step that comes before GEO (Geostationary Earth Orbit), where GTO is highly elliptical with the perigee very low and the apogee at Geostationary altitude. The final circularization burn is typically performed by the satellite itself, so that the second stage does not end up in GEO (SpaceX usually disposes of second stages by having them deorbit into the ocean).
As such, it would likely be difficult to convince SpaceX to perform a F9 mission to GEO because this would likely result in a large chunk of space debris hanging around in a "prime real estate" orbit.
That said, if they wanted to do so, the second stage engine (Merlin 1D Vacuum) has about 981kN of thrust and an isp of 348 seconds. The second stage, having an empty mass of  about 3900 kg. In order to transfer from GTO to GEO, we need a (generous) 1800 m/s of $\Delta v$.
Now we ask the question "Assuming we are in GTO with the maximum payload and the second stage is empty, how much of the payload mass do we need to convert into fuel to make the GEO burn?"
Using the rocket equation:
$$\Delta v = I_{sp} \cdot g_0 \cdot \ln{\frac{m_0}{m_f}} $$
we can rearrange it to find the mass ratio:
$$\frac{m_0}{m_f} = \exp{\frac{\Delta v}{I_{sp} \cdot g_0}}$$
Plugging in the values on the right-hand side of the equation, we know that the mass ratio will need to be about $1.7$ so we can set up the two formulas:
$$ \frac{3900 + m_{newPayload} + m_{addedFuel}}{3900 + m_{newPayload}} = 1.7 $$
$$ m_{newPayload} + m_{addedFuel} = 8300 $$
We can solve this system of equations and arrive at $m_{fuel} \thickapprox 5000 \text{kg}$ and $m_{newPayload} \thickapprox 3300 \text{kg}$.
So, from a pure performance perspective, and ignoring any deorbit, a F9 second stage could theoretically put around 3300 kg into GEO, although this is ignoring potential fuel-volume constraints.
This is somewhat in line with the other numbers SpaceX has given us. Specifically they claim around 4020kg to Mars, and since a TMI (Trans-mars injection burn) is about 3.6 km/s of $\Delta v$ and GTO plus GEO is maybe 4.3 km/s of $\Delta v$, the figure seems reasonable.

Can you clarify if the 1800 m/s delta-v number you used is the value from GTO to a geosynchronous orbit, or a geostationary orbit?

I actually couldn't find the 1800 m/s value in the paper you referenced. The values in the charts there are all quite a bit higher. I think 2700 from Figure 11 is probably the right value assuming Falcon 9 launches from KSC.

@phil1008 It's on page 10 line 3

Thank you for this answer. Could you please also include how an ASDS/RTLS landing would affect the capacity?

The delta-v that you need to get from GTO to Geostationary Orbit can be found with
$$\Delta V= \sqrt{V_\mathrm{t,a}^2+V_\mathrm{GEO}^2-2V_\mathrm{t,a}V_\mathrm{GEO}\mathrm{cos}(\Delta i)}$$
(ref)
Where:
$V_\mathrm{t,a}$ is the velocity magnitude at the apogee of the transfer orbit (1.64 km/s),
$V_\mathrm{GEO}$ is the velocity of the Geostationary orbit (3.0746 km/s),
and
$\Delta i$ is the inclination of the GTO, which is 28.5° for Kennedy Space Center which is likely where Falcon 9 would launch from for this kind of mission.
Plugging in these numbers we get...
$$\Delta V= 2.78\ \mathrm{km/s}$$
If we use the vacuum Merlin exhaust velocity of 3.05 km/s (from Wikipedia which points here)
$$\frac{m_0}{m_f} = exp\left(\frac{\Delta V}{V_\mathrm{Exhaust}}\right)=2.48$$
The dry mass of the Falcon 9 second stage is estimated to be 3900 kg and its payload to GTO is 8300 kg.
$$\frac{m_\mathrm{Dry} + m_\mathrm{GTOPayload}}{m_\mathrm{Dry} + m_\mathrm{GEOPayload}} = \frac{m_\mathrm{Dry} + m_\mathrm{Extra Propellant} + m_\mathrm{GEOPayload}}{m_\mathrm{Dry} + m_\mathrm{GEOPayload}}$$
$$ = \frac{3900 + 8300}{3900 + m_\mathrm{GEOPayload}} = 2.48 $$
$$ \frac{3900 + 8300}{2.48} - 3900 = m_\mathrm{GEOPayload} $$
So the geostationary payload is 1008 kg.
The payload to GTO for the cheapest configuration of the Falcon 9 (which I have to assume is the Return To Landing Site (RTLS) version) is 5500 kg.

If you used that number for the payload mass to GTO, then you would get a payload to geostationary of minus 118 kg.
The Automated Spaceport Drone Ship (ASDS) configuration performs roughly 33% better than the RTLS configuration, according to this site - but this is rough so take it with a grain of salt.
If we assume $5500(1.33) = 7333 \mathrm{\ kg}$ to GTO, then the ASDS configuration would be able to deliver 619 kg to a geostationary orbit.

5.5 millitesla TO GTO! Yes I know, metric tons or tonnes or whatever, typically denoted with 't'.

So the falcon 9 is unable to do an RTLS landing after a GEO mission, even with no payload at all?

@Arsenal Yes, that's a screenshot of the SpaceX website. It's weird that they use "mT" units in the footnote under the price, only provide the GTO payload in that footnote, and then used 'kg' for the expendable capabilities to LEO, GTO, and Mars.

3.05 km/s is the vacuum Isp of the sea-level Merlin engine. The Isp of the vacuum engine used in the second stage is significantly higher due to its big nozzle.

Also, the delta-v required is around 1.81 km/s, not 2.78. This answer is wrong on multiple counts and @Starship should unaccept it: https://chatgpt.com/share/672d3450-6f1c-800a-b8c1-1b0454e916b9

You are stating that the answer is wrong but your reference is a broken link to ChatGPT? Please explain exactly what you think is incorrect.
